# PHP instantiating child class

Tags: php, class, parent, instantiation

I'm trying to become an object-oriented coder here, so I'm giving myself some simple tasks.
I built a class that displays all the images in a given directory.  That worked fine, so I separated that class into two classes, one to read the filenames in the directory and pass them into an array, and one to parse that array and display the pictures.  The method in the child class is exactly the same as it was when it was in the parent class (except of course substituting parent:: for this->).

Now it seems when I instantiate the child class and call its method, nothing happens at all.

**Classes:**

```
class Picfind
{
   public function findPics($dir){
       $files = array();
       $i=0;
       $handle = opendir($dir);
       while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
           $extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1));
           if($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'gif' || $extension == 'png'){
                // now use $file as you like
                $i++;
                $files['file' . $i] = $file;
           }
       }
       return $files;
    }
}

class DisplayPics extends Picfind
{

    function diplayPics($dir) 
    {
        echo 'displayPics method called';

        foreach(parent::findPics($dir) as $key => $val) {
            echo '<img src="' . $dir . $val . '" img><br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

**Instantiation:**

```
include("class.picFind.php");
$Myclass = new DisplayPics();
$Myclass->displayPics('./images/');
```

Comment: You have your whole design wrong.  While hakre certainly gave you a better design, you still could use some improvement. See my post below for details.

Comment: You didn't even considered the other answers. Know that there is not *one* right design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To be honest: your whole design is wrong.**

1. **`DisplayPics` shouldn't inherit from `Picfind`.**  Honestly, either have `Picfind` have a display method, or have `DisplayPics` take the output from `Picfind`.  Think, does the following make sense: "DisplayPics is a PicFind."?  If not, it's probably wrong.
2. **Classes normally aren't verbs.**  A better name would be `Pictures`, with  `find` and `display` methods.  In your case, you are finding something in a directory, which leads to the next point:
3. **You should make use of the PHP [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) class.** This way, you can do whatever you'd like with the files you find.  You'll have all the information about the file available to you, and it's integrated nicely with PHP.
4. **You need a separation of concerns.** This is what hakre's suggestion is all about. Reducing dependencies and decoupling things is normally helpful.

---

```
/**
 * ExtensionFinder will find all the files in a directory that have the given
 * extensions.
 */
class ExtensionFinder extends DirectoryIterator {
    
    protected $extensions =  array();
    
    public function __contruct($directory) {
        parent::__construct($directory);
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Sets the extensions for the iterator. 
     * @param array $extensions The extensions you want to get (without the dot).
     */
    public function extensions(array $extensions) {
        $this->extensions = $extensions;
    }
    
    /**
     * Determines if this resource is valid.  If you return false from this 
     * function, the iterator will stop.  
     * @return boolean Returns true if the value is a file with proper extension.
     */
    public function valid() {
        if (parent::valid()) {
            $current = parent::current();
            
            if ($current->isFile()) {
                // if the extensions array is empty or null, we simply accept it.
                if (empty($this->extensions)) {
                    //otherwise filter it
                    if (in_array($current->getExtension(), $this->extensions)) {
                         return true;
                    } else {
                        parent::next();
                        return $this->valid();
                    }
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                parent::next();
                return $this->valid();
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        
    }
}

class PictureFinder extends ExtensionFinder {
    public function __construct($directory) {
        parent::__construct($directory);
        
        $this->extensions = array (
            'jpg',
            'gif',
            'png'
        );
    }
}
```

**How to use:**

```
$iterator = new PictureFinder('img/');
foreach($iterator as $file) {
    //do whatever you want with the picture here.
    echo $file->getPathname()."\n";
}
```

Note that you could use the `ExtensionFinder` class I defined above to find files of ANY extension.  That could potentially be more useful than simply finding images, but I defined a `PictureFinder` class for you for that specific use-case.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote that you want to learn object oriented programming. What about the following:

```
class PicFinder
{
   /**
    * @return array
    */
   public function inDirectory($directory)
   {
       return // array of files
   }
}

class PicPresentation
{
    public function present(array $pictures)
    {
        // your presentation code
    }
}


$path = '/your/path';
$datasource = new PicFinder();
$presentation = new PicPresentation();
$pictures = $datasource->inDirectory($path);
$presentation->present($pictures);
```

Keep things separated and loosely coupled. One object should be responsible for one thing, e.g. one object to obtain the list of pictures from a directory and another one for the presentation. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I was going step by step turning something procedural into something object oriented and was hoping to end up with something like you have there.

Comment: Good advice, but I'm going to add another route.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I ended up doing something very similar, but also passing the directory into the values in my array of file names, so that when I call on that array as an object anywhere else, I can work with its values anywhere.

I also moved the functionality that parses the file extensions into the display method, so that I can use the first class to return an array of file names.  

I guess for practice I'll separate that functionality into its own class as well, and make it so the user can pass an argument that will determine which types of files will be displayed.

Comment: Instead of the array you can create a `PictureCollection` that contains that base path or whichever other meta-information you need as well next to the array of pictures.

Comment: Honestly, you are recreating existing behavior already defined in PHP.  See my answer for an option that allows you to get ANY data from the file, including size, full path, path without name, etc.

Comment: @LeviMorrison: You should differ between the domain the user talks about and file-system abstraction as the SPL offers it. Sure you can or even should use the SPL file system objects within your domain model, but you must not make your domain model the SPL.

Comment: @hakre You have some valid design points, don't get me wrong, but almost everyone SHOULD be using the SPL.  It's name is the Standard PHP Library and is included by default on most installations for that reason.

Comment: But a picture means something else here than file. Picture is related to file, but it's different as well. So with so much stuff in common, it's good to know the difference. That's not speaking against the SPL in any direction.

Comment: @hakre it seems at least 2 more people agree with me than you.  But, there isn't usually a one right way.  I do like that you've suggested a separation of concerns, but because the original poster is new to the OO world of PHP, I guess I just expected more.  Also, I added a note in my post and directly recognized your post to emphasize the fact that I agree.

Comment: @Levi Morrison: The SPL has no files collection, it only offers file-system abstraction in your case. If you want to separate concerns, you need to separate them. De-Couple from the filesystem for the parts you can. In doing so, make use of file-system abstraction the SPL has to offer. But for a pictures collection, implement an iterator from the SPL for example, that's nice for collections.

Comment: @Hakre I really don't see your point.  In either of our suggestions, the user is still very tightly bound to the filesystem.  Admittedly, you could implement `inDatabase` in your approach but not in mine.  Fair enough. But what's the likelihood he's pulling pictures from a file-system and a database and would want the same abstraction for both?  Seems unlikely to me.

Comment: I'm just saying that file-system abstraction (and the SPL offers ready-made objects for that) and domain models are two pair of shoes. Nothing more or less.

Answer (score 0):

$Myclass->displayPics('./images/');
is calling the constructor and nothing is happening.
You have a typo in your function name aswell.

Comment: What constructor?  Is there a constructor by default?  Would it be the constructor of the parent or child class?

Comment: php has 2 conventions for constructors. __construct or the class name. So a class called 'test' will have a constructor of 'test'

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that design instead:

```
class PicFinder
{
    public function findPics($dir){
       ...
    }
}

class PicDisplayer
{
    protected $picFinder;

    public function __construct() {
        // Default pic finder
        $this->setPicFinder(new PicFinder());
    }

    public function diplayPics($dir)  {
        echo 'displayPics method called';

        foreach($this->getPicFinder()->findPics($dir) as $key => $val) {
            echo '<img src="' . $dir . $val . '" img><br/>';
        }
    }

    protected function setPicFinder(PicFinder $picFinder) {
        $this->picFinder = $picFinder;
    }
    protected function getPicFinder() {
        return $this->picFinder;
    }
}
```

That way you only use PicDisplayer and don't care how it finds the pics. But you can still change the "PicFinder" if needed, by extending the PicFinder class and implementing a specific behavior.